# Dialogflow agent git versioning

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking for a solution that allows my team to collaborate in the development of a single Dialogflow agent, because the typical scenario is that 2 or more developers work on the same agent.

Usually for other kind of technologies we adopt git for source code versioning (also for webhooks in example) applying the proper branching strategy.

We tried to use git also for agents exports, but in this case it seems to be impossible because we are facing issues in merging intents ids (that seems to be generated with a not well known way).

Then in this scenario, we need to synchronize each other, for consistency checks, before exporting and committing the zip to git, losing the chance to leverage the power of git.

Searching with Google I got that we can solve the problem start using such framework like [Narratory](https://narratory.io/).

Said that, my questions are:

1. Do you know if is there any way ther to accomplish our need without using Narratoy?
2. Do you know if exist alternative to Narratory?